# How to show total price of items in Woocommerce Cart Widget?

Tags: wordpress, widget, woocommerce, cart

Currently my Woocommerce cart widget look like this (witout total price of items):

```
img1     Coffee
         2 x $5
-------------------
img2     Biscuit
         1 x $10
-------------------
img3     Cheese
         3 x $10
-------------------
Subtotal: $50
```

I want to change it to (with total price of quantity items):

```
img1     Coffee
         2 x $5        $10
---------------------------
img2     Biscuit
         1 x $10       $10
---------------------------
img3     Cheese
         3 x $10       $30
---------------------------
Subtotal:              $50
```

As you can see the second example of Cart Widget shows the total price of the items.

Can someone please help me out?
Thanks in advance! :)!

Answer (score 2):

Modify the woocommerce plugin to achieve this in following manner :

Make one folder in your theme folder and name it **woocommerce** and in new created woocommerce folder, create another folder with **cart** name.

So now it will look something like **wp-content > themes > your-theme > woocommerce > cart**.

Now go to your plugin directory and follow below path :

`wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > templates > cart`

When you go in above path, you will find one file named as `mini-cart.php`. Copy that file and paste it to the directory which we created at top of that answer.

`wp-content > themes > your-theme > woocommerce > cart > mini-cart.php`.

Now its time to modify the code in **wp-content > themes > your-theme > woocommerce > cart > mini-cart.php**.

Simply replace all code with following code:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Mini-cart
     *
     * Contains the markup for the mini-cart, used by the cart widget
     *
     * @author      WooThemes
     * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
     * @version     2.1.0
     */

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); ?>

    <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget <?php echo $args['list_class']; ?>">

        <?php if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) : ?>

            <?php
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                    $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {

                        $product_name  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        $thumbnail     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        $product_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        echo "<p>".$product_price."</p>";
                        ?>
                        <li>
                        <?php if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) { ?>
                            <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name; ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $product_id ); ?>">
                                <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name; ?>
                            </a>
                        <?php } ?>
                            <?php echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>
                            <?php   $new_product_price_array = explode ( get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(), $product_price); 
                                    $new_product_price = number_format((float)$new_product_price_array[1] * $cart_item['quantity'], 2, '.', '');

                            ?>
                            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s=%s%s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price,get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(), $new_product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <li class="empty"><?php _e( 'No products in the cart.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></li>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </ul><!-- end product list -->

    <?php if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) : ?>

        <p class="total"><strong><?php _e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></p>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?>

        <p class="buttons">
            <a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" class="button wc-forward"><?php _e( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_checkout_url(); ?>" class="button checkout wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        </p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart' ); ?>
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: You can accept that answer so that in future it helps other people as well. Happy Coding !

Comment: Hi @Rohil_PHPBeginner - Appreciate this was 3 years ago, but I am trying to achieve something similar and display the **total number of items in the cart** by the bottom/top of the cart widget...is this possible?