# Ajaxify custom mini-cart widget in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, cart

I have added a menu to my website which displays the cart total also the product details, qty and price of each item. This only works when the page is refreshed manually or redirected to the cart.

```
                    global $woocommerce;

                    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
                    $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

                    echo '<li><a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/cart/" class="parents"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart - ' .  WC()->cart->get_cart_total() . '</a>';
                    echo '<ul class="mega_menu cart">';
                    echo '<li class="mega_sub">';
                    echo '<ul>';

                    foreach($items as $item => $values) {
                      $_product = $values['data']->post;
                      $link = get_permalink($_product);
                      $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($_product);
                      $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
                      $total = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
                      echo '<li>' . $image . '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $_product->post_title . ' <br /><span style=" text-transform:lowercase;"> ' . $currency.$price . ' x ' . $values['quantity'] .'</span></a></li>';
                    }

                    echo '<li><a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/cart/">Go to Checkout</a></li>';
                    echo '</ul></li></ul>';
```

I have found this function but it only updates the cart total and price.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/

Would I need to re-write the code for the sub-menu or is there another solution I can update my cart items on the AJAX function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really outdated with errors and mistakes. Also Woocommerce already includes a usable mini-cart widget *(with an editable template)*.

1) The html/php code to replace yours *(in your themes hearder.php file I suppose)*:

```
// echo '<ul>'; // (Used for testing)
echo '<li><a class="parents mini-cart-count" href="'.wc_get_cart_url().'"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart - ';
## Ajax refresh: Cart subtotal near the cart icon
echo '<span id="mcart-stotal">'.WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal().'</span>';
echo '</a>';
echo '<ul class="mega_menu cart">';
echo '<li class="mega_sub">';
echo '<span id="mcart-widget">';
## Ajax refresh: Mini cart widget
woocommerce_mini_cart();
echo '</span>';
echo '</li></ul>';
// echo '</li></ul>'; // (Used for testing)
```

---

2) The code that will Ajax refresh your mini cart subtotal and widget:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'wc_mini_cart_ajax_refresh' );
function wc_mini_cart_ajax_refresh( $fragments ){
    ## 1. Refreshing mini cart subtotal amount
    $fragments['#mcart-stotal'] = '<span id="mcart-stotal">'.WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal().'</span>';

    ## 2. Refreshing cart subtotal
    ob_start();
    echo '<span id="mcart-widget">';
    woocommerce_mini_cart();
    echo '</span>';
    $fragments['#mcart-widget'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Related: [Display cart item count in Woocommerce cart widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607309/display-cart-item-count-in-woocommerce-cart-widget/50608120#50608120)

Comment: Thanks, yes I was aware there was a minicart.php it was just the AJAX refresh I was stuck on I will try and implement this solution and update when working.

Cheers